# Salesforce connection problem with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to connect to salesforce dev env through eclipse. for this, i am creating a force.com project, given the required details to access salesforce metadata.(like username, pwd and org type - selected test.salesforce.com).

When I clicked on next button - a pop window appears saying "unable to fetch organization details with user name i have given. i tried to change the proxy settings too, that does not help me. 
in preferences->network settings --> i have selected native proxy type settings.

kindly suggest the solution.

Comment: Have a look at your user within the Salesforce UI.  Down the bottom is a list of login attempts.  Are you seeing anything there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the access token with your password or go to network setting and whitelist your IP.

To whitelist your Ip search network setting and add your IP there.

To update the TLS in Eclipse follow these steps:

Force.com IDE Plug-In for Eclipse
If you use Java 7, you can’t create or edit projects using the Force.com IDE plug-in for Eclipse unless you disable TLS 1.0. (TLS 1.0 is disabled by default in Java 8.) Update your eclipse.ini file to include this line.

-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

The location of the eclipse.ini file depends on your operating system. For more information, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207#IDE)

Comment: should this be on eclipse?to add ip address. i am seeing the two boxes - proxy entries and proxy bypasses. in which i am supposed to add?

Comment: @Venkatz No you need to whitelist IP on SF.

Comment: i have add my sys ip to sf. and tried to login, getting the same error. showing tsl1.0  service is disabled

Comment: @Venkatz check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add your IP to setup->network access page

[image]

then you will be able to create a project in eclipse

Comment: i followed the same thing. still getting the error.

Comment: you can add your ip at profile level and try once.

Comment: i am sys admin profile, the ip already was included at this profile.